# Nexus3: move a specific Maven repository into an another blob store

Tags: maven, nexus, nexus3

I've just installed Nexus 3 by upgrading from Nexus 2 and noticed that every Maven repository is now in the default blob store. I would like to move the releases repository to be hosted from a separate blob store. What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. You would need to recreate the repository with a different blob store. We have some future plans for supporting something like this, but that's a bit off. Pop over to https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS and file an issue if you would, it will help raise awareness of your need :)

Comment: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12016 which is in progress as of this comment.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's also noteworthy that when you upgrade, you can select what blobstore you want the upgraded repos to fall in as documented [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Upgrade+Procedures#UpgradeProcedures-UpgradingContent); specifically 'Repository Defaults' section 'Destination' field.

So, for people who haven't upgraded yet or who are willing to rerun (basically scrap and start over) the upgrade, it is possible to get things organized as you want before hand.  First, you can first create the blobstores you want things to be organized in and then during the upgrade process select where you want things to go.

UPDATE: As shown in [NEXUS-12016](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12016), this is now possible for Professional (licensed) instances (for hosted repositories) as of 3.28.0.